# res/drawable files location on device after installing apk

Tags: android, android-drawable

Where is the location of `res/drawable` after installing an apk?

I mean the location on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawables remain inside the APK, as do other resources.

Comment: Could you please, tell me where is the correct path to save pictures that will be used in future by the app and also saved by the same app?

Comment: @Elkin: Your app can write to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getFilesDir()`).